# Laravel - Seeing Symfony Exception page instead of Spatie Ignition

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8, laravel-exceptions

In my composer file I have `"spatie/laravel-ignition": "^1.2"` however when an exception is thrown I am seeing the Symfony exception page rather than Ignition (shown below).

`.env` has the following:

```
APP_ENV="local"
APP_DEBUG="true"
```

Config files are published and contain default value.

Am I missing something really obvious to get this up and running?

[image]

Comment: Did you manage to find a fix?